# multi bounded methods in a statically typed language?

Tags: methods, types, bounded-types, static-language

Sorry the title is kinda wrong. Because I was thinking about method binding, when this question came up.
Example with some pseudo code..

```
interface A
interface B

val z: A & B = [object of a class that implements A and B];
```

Is their any statically language that supports this feature? 
-> Resolution of references to both types of z. 
Or do I have some logic problems and it isn't possible?

Comment: C# generics kind of supports this via the `where` constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in scala with traits:

```
trait A
trait B
class Z extends A with B

val z: A with B = new Z
```

Comment: Thank you! Lots of scala concepts are really nice :) I need to get more into it

Comment: I have just looked with javap at the bytecode - it looks like Scala is doing this with checkcast instruction whenever additional types are used. In this example B. Poor compiler has to do many things in scala.